# Runtime error em python 3.8 - URI

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Estou praticando uns exemplos no URI Online Judge e cheguei a este exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tentei a seguinte solução:

```py
numeros = input().split();
N1, N2, N3, N4 = float(numeros[0]), float(numeros[1]), float(numeros[2]), float(numeros[3])

NotaExame = float(input())

M = (N1 * 2 + N2 * 3 + N3 * 4 + N4) / 10
print("Media:", M)

if M >= 7:
    print("Aluno aprovado.")
elif M < 5:
    print("Aluno reprovado.")
elif 5 <= M <= 6.9:
    print("Aluno em exame.")
    print("Nota do exame:", NotaExame)

    NovaMedia = (M + NotaExame) / 2

    if NovaMedia >= 5:
        print("Aluno aprovado.")
    else:
        print("Aluno reprovado.")

    print("Media final:", NovaMedia)
```

Porém, obtive o seguinte erro na linha 4:

```
RUNTIME ERROR

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 4, in 
    NotaExame = float(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

O URI é bem rígido nas suas entradas e saídas saírem idênticas a como ele deseja.

Coloquei aquela **NotaExame** alí porquê ao colocar dentro do `elif` da linha 13 (Pois o exemplo deixa a entender que esta entrada é para ocorrer apenas se o aluno ficar na condição para realizar o exame) acabou resultando em **Wrong Answer (5%)**, então achei melhor tentar corrigir o **Runtime Error**, que acredito estar mais próximo do resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O enunciado deixa bem claro que a nota do exame só é fornecida se o aluno estiver de exame. Senão, não haverá o que ler, e por isso dará erro ao tentar usar `input`. Então mova a leitura da nota do exame para dentro da condição específica (se deu erro, foi por outro motivo).

Enfim, também dá para mudar um pouco os `if`'s:

```
n1, n2, n3, n4 = map(float, input().split())
media = (2 * n1 + 3 * n2 + 4 * n3 + n4) / 10
print(f'Media: {media:.1f}')

if media < 5:
    print('Aluno reprovado.')
elif media < 7:
    print('Aluno em exame.')
    exame = float(input())
    print(f'Nota do exame: {exame:.1f}')
    media = (media + exame) / 2
    if media >= 5:
        print('Aluno aprovado.')
    else:
        print('Aluno reprovado.')
    print(f'Media final: {media:.1f}')
else:
    print('Aluno aprovado.')
```

Primeiro eu testo se a média é menor que 5. Se não entrar no primeiro `if`, é porque com certeza é maior ou igual a 5, então eu não preciso testar isso de novo no `elif` (basta ver se é menor que 7). Se não entrou no `if` nem no `elif`, é porque com certeza é maior ou igual a 7 então não precisa testar isso de novo (se chegou no `else` é porque está aprovado).

Repare que usei *f-string* (com um `f` antes das aspas de abertura), juntamente com o formato `.1f` para mostrar os números com 1 casa decimal (um dos requisitos do exercício). Talvez seja isso que deu problema no seu caso, deve ter casos que a média fica com mais de uma casa decimal, mas o exercício pede que as notas sejam impressas com apenas uma casa (como não foi dado o link, não consigo testar).

Comment: Amigo, daqui a pouco irei testar sua solução. Não mandei o link, pois para poder realizar o teste e submeter, tem que haver uma conta no URI, mas segue o link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1040